# Hyper-V: Guest external internet access

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines, dhcp, gateway

**Following setup:**

Host machine has 1 physical NIC

Host OS = Win Server 2008 R2 (hosted in data center)

Guest OS = Win Home Server 2011

Network setup basically as described [here](http://www.hyper-v-mart.com/HowTo/Configure_HyperV_Virtual_Network.aspx) or [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19359-hyper-v-virtual-switch-manager.html).

**Goal:** Connect from within the guest VM to the internet.

**Question #1:** How is this supposed to work? My guest OS has a static IP "A" (a real, external one, so not a local 192.168.x.x one [same applies for all other involved IPs]). In order to reach the internet it now needs to route through the host OS (IP "B") and the router (IP "C") in the data center.

I can ping from "A" to "B", but my guest cannot see the router/gateway (Wireshark keeps showing ARP requests regarding who knows "C"). Shouldn't my host OS (which of course knows the router and vice versa) be able to deliver that information to my guest? If yes, then any ideas what might prevent it to do so?

**Note:** I test-wise set up an additional "internal" hyper-V network connection between the host and the client in the hope that this could help the gateway propagation, and eventually it did...at least my guest started to "know" the gateway and connected through it to the internet. So is this the only way? Is it the correct way or must something else have been responsible for the resolution?

**Question #2:** If I remove the static IP "A" from my guest and set IP retrieval back to auto, it receives a local IP, but from who? I don't not have a DHCP server role on my host OS and according to question #1, my guest cannot see the router (which would be the logical next DHCP provider from my point of view)?

Comment: Guest network traffic doesn't "route" through the host OS. The host does not act as a "router" for the guest. Set the DG on the guest to be the router, not the host. with the guest in DHCP mode, what ip address is it being assigned?

Comment: If I set the DG to be data center router and assign no static IP to the guest, it gets a local one 169.254.x.x. The host cannot `ping` guest though _("Transmit failed. General error")_. Who assigned that IP? I assumed the data center router, but it doesn't know about it, since it relays the `tracert` command to other nodes further outside the data center.

Comment: Also in another VM the internet connection worked with the setup of the "internal" connection between host and guest. Will have to investigate again why...

Comment: The ip address that the guest is getting (169.254.x.x) is an APIPA ip address. It's not usable in getting internet access. You need to assign a valid ip address to the guest.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that (wasn't of the APIPA concept as a DHCP fallback though), which is why in Q#1 I assigned a static IP address (144.76.x.x), but the guest doesn't find the gateway, so it cannot connect to the internet.
Also: See my _note_ above as an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: NO - if you set up a public network in Hyper-V then the host IP and the Client IP coexist. The NIC basically gets routed through a virtual switch - clients and host are on the same ethernet segment connected to the outside world. NO ROUTING.

Question 2: Either a DHCP server somewhere or an automatic local Address that is negotiated. Note that "somewhere" can be the data center - again: The host and the client share a public ethernet port. Pretty much like putting in a separate NIC for the client and then a hardware switch in front - just that the switch is virtual. The client will send a DHCP request and Hyper-V will forward it into the data center.